# Need to generate attribute to the class at run time

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a class with out have any attribute. At runtime I need to add the custom attribute to the class. My Requirement is, I created the Class without any attribute, at runtime based on some value only I can able to decide whehter I have to add CORS attribute to the class or not. Can anyone suggest me the solution.

Comment: The short answer is - this isn't possible. This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . What is your underlying problem?

Comment: Don't. Use some other CORS (policy?) mechanism that's *designed* for runtime use.

Comment: Well, it´s possible, but I doubt it´s what you want. *Why* do you think you have to add attributes to an existing class at runtime?

Comment: @HimBromBeere thanks for your interest. My requirement is, I have done some restriction inside the attribute that is applicable only for specific call for example for speicific user. That is why i need to attribute at runtime.

Comment: `That is why i need to attribute at runtime.` You don't need 'to attribute at runtime'. You need an attribute there at compile time, with an `if` condition in it to have two different sets of behaviour at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Attributes are designed to be compile time (you can't even put anything in them that isn't a compile-time constant), so, shortly put, you can't. Whatever problem you're trying to solve you took the wrong approach.